# Checking and merging case-insensitive duplicates within a case-sensitive dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I'm looking for a good way to combine elements of a case-sensitive dictionary that have the same key in different cases.

In my case, my dictionary is a `Dictionary<string, SortedSet<int>>` item, and for example has the following values:

```
{ 
  DictKey1: [0, 1, 2],
  DictKey2: [3, 4, 5],
  dictKEY1: [2, 6, 7]
}
```

(I'm reading this data from a file and have no control over how this file is created).

I want to combine the values of Key1 and key1 into a single `KeyValuePair<string, SortedSet<int>>`, and remove the duplicate entry key1, so that my dictionary now looks like this:

```
{ 
  DictKey1: [0, 1, 2, 6, 7],
  DictKey2: [3, 4, 5]
}
```

The code I have now uses an iterative approach, going over each of the keys and comparing them, combining the matching keys' values and adding them to a list that is then iterated over, removing them from the original dictionary. This works, but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant or efficient solution that I'm missing.

This is my code:

```
Dictionary<string, SortedSet<int>> myDict;
var keysToRemove = new List<string>();
var otherDict = myDict.JsonClone();
foreach (var item in myDict)
{
    otherDict.Remove(item.Key);
    if (otherDict.Keys.Count == 0)
        break;
    foreach (var otherItem in otherDict)
    {
        if (item.Key.Equals(otherItem.Key, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            item.Value.UnionWith(otherItem.Value);
            keysToRemove.Add(otherItem.Key);
        }
    }
}

foreach (var key in keysToRemove)
    myDict.Remove(key);
```

**Edit:** For clarification, I need one of the keys' case to be preserved. Simply converting the keys to all upper-case or lower-case would just cause me more headaches haha.

Comment: `This works, but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant or efficient solution` what assumptions do you have that warrant there is?

Comment: @Codexer The assumption that there are people smarter than me out there who might approach this problem differently. I'm always seeking to learn and improve myself through others' insights.

Comment: Have you done any code analysis, profiling and or diagnostics? If not, this is a great place to start.

Comment: If you want casing in keys to be irrelevant, why not just create the dictionary case-insensitive to begin with? It would depend on how you fill up the dictionary, however. If you look up the key, and add a new element to the sorted list it is bound to, just using case insensitive keys should work. If you're just *adding* keys and values to the dictionary and you get already case sensitive keys from somewhere else, not so much.

Comment: Can you show how you fill the dictionary to begin with?

Comment: Also, do you have any preferences about which of the keys is kept? In your example you have `Key1` vs `key1`, is it important that one is kept, and not the other?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Unfortunately I'm reading this dictionary from a file, and I have no control over how this file is created, hence my problem. And it's not very important which of the keys is kept, no, though I would prefer it to be the upper case one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GroupBy` to group the similar keys.  Then `Aggregate` and `UnionWith` to combine them.

```
var otherDict = new Dictionary<string, SortedSet<int>>();
var grouped = myDict.Keys.ToList().GroupBy(k => k.ToLower());

foreach(var g in grouped) 
    otherDict[g.First()] = g.Aggregate(
        new SortedSet<int>(), // seed
        (a,b) => { a.UnionWith(myDict[b]); return a; }
    );

myDict = otherDict;
```

---

Edited to reflect OP's need to choose a key casing that reflects the state of one of the original keys.

Comment: This creates a new key with all the correct values, but it doesn't remove the duplicate keys, and it does completely get rid of the upper case of the both keys, one of which I would prefer to preserve if possible.

Comment: @Handelo could you please update your post to include these details. Currently it doesn't and it doesn't help anyone either that *has already answered based on your post*.

Comment: I don't believe you're correct when you say it doesn't remove the duplicate keys.  But I do see what you're saying with respect to keeping at least one of the original casings.  I updated my code to reflect this need.

Comment: @pwilcox You're right, there was a small error with the original code that I fixed but ended up adding my own mistake. This works perfectly now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can remove one loop if you don't care about the case of the keys at the end of the process. You can also remove that clone step.

```
foreach (var item in myDict)
{
    var keyLower = item.Key.ToLower();
    if (!otherDict.TryGetValue(keyLower, out var arr))
        otherDict[keyLower] = item.Value;
    else
        otherDict[keyLower] = item.Value.UnionWith(arr.Value);
}

myDict = otherDict;
```

The above builds up a new dictionary with merged entries. If you care about the case of the keys, I would suggest using a case insensitive dictionary, but use your preferred key-case for each of the keys.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but although it doesn't really matter to me which of the keys' case is preserved, one of them must be. For example, If I have the two keys "WithQC" and "withQC", either will work, but "withqc" is not an option.

A case insensitive dictionary is unfortunately not an option, since I'm reading this data from a file and have no control over how this file is created. Reading it into a case-insensitive dictionary will simply overwrite one of the keys.